# Create a left join using a minimum column value?

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables and I want to select all rows from the reviews table where author is `usr1` and join it to the posts table where the threadid and tid columns match, but using `MIN(positionID)`.

Here is my reviews table:

```
cid     tID         author     
 1   |    1      |  usr1     |    
 2   |    2      |  usr2     |    
 3   |    3      |  usr1     |   
 4   |    3      |  usr1     |
```

And the posts table:

```
 id   threadID    rating        positionID
 1   |    1      |  99.99      |   1
 2   |    1      |  150.00     |   2
 3   |    2      |  33.10      |   1
 4   |    2      |  10.00      |   2
 5   |    3      |  16.00      |   1
 6   |    3      |  45.00      |   2
 7   |    3      |  75.00      |   3
```

Expected result:

```
cid     tID         author    rating 
 1   |    1      |  usr1     |    99.99
 3   |    3      |  usr1     |    16.00
 4   |    3      |  usr1     |    16.00
```

I tried few different queries after some reading, like this one below, but I am getting NULL in few rows:

```
SELECT * FROM Reviews AS R
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from posts GROUP BY positionID) AS P on P.threadID=R.tID
WHERE c.author_name='usr1'
```

Maybe left join is not the one I need?

Comment: Why does your result set have a repeated row?

Comment: result set does not have repeated row. cid is different

Comment: But the rest of it is the same?

Comment: yes. there are few other columns too which are different. omitted for clarity. As long as I can get the min(positionID), I can manage the rest

Comment: Just another question - will there ever be a case when minimum positionid is not 1?

Comment: Thats the problem. In most cases, it will be one. But if '1' gets deleted, then min will be 2, etc.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Dumb questions? That's what google's for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  threadID INT NOT NULL,
  rating DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  positionID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id));

INSERT INTO posts(threadid, rating, positionid) VALUES
(1, 99.99, 1),
(1, 150.00, 2),
(2, 33.10, 1),
(2, 10.00, 2),
(3, 45.00, 2),
(3, 75.00, 3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reviews;

CREATE TABLE reviews(
  cid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tid INT NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(cid));

INSERT INTO reviews(tid, author) VALUES
(1, 'usr1'),
(2, 'usr2'),
(3, 'usr1'),
(3, 'usr1');

SELECT cid,tid,author,rating
  FROM posts p
  JOIN
     ( SELECT threadid,MIN(positionid) min_positionid FROM posts GROUP BY threadid) x
    ON x.threadid = p.threadid
   AND x.min_positionid = p.positionid
  JOIN reviews r ON r.tid = p.threadid
 WHERE author = 'usr1'
;
+-----+-----+--------+--------+
| cid | tid | author | rating |
+-----+-----+--------+--------+
|   1 |   1 | usr1   |  99.99 |
|   3 |   3 | usr1   |  45.00 |
|   4 |   3 | usr1   |  45.00 |
+-----+-----+--------+--------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2669/7

Comment: I think it's better when you add a little explanation to your SQL rather than a giant block of code, it's not going to help someone who's already confused.

Answer (score 1):

Left join is not the right one to use here. Outer joins are used if you want to get ALL rows from one table, and only rows from another when they match. It appears here that you want to get only rows where a corresponding row exists in both tables.

You can start by writing this, to get the rows you want:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reviews r
JOIN posts p ON p.threadid = r.tid
WHERE r.author = 'usr1';
```

As far as getting the minimum position - it will likely always be 1 if it starts at 1, so you can filter on that. That should leave you with this query:

```
SELECT r.cid, r.tid, r.author, p.rating
FROM reviews r
JOIN posts p ON p.threadid = r.tid
WHERE r.author = 'usr1' AND p.positionid = 1;
```

---

However, if you want to get the minimum position id, I would do the following, though this seems a bit tricky there may be a better way:

This is a little trick to get the first item in a group. In this case, you want the earliest positionid in the groups of threadids:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM posts pt
  WHERE pt.threadid = p.threadid AND pt.positionid <= p.positionid
  ) <= 1;
```

You can use that subquery to join with your reviews table like this:

```
SELECT r.cid, r.tid, r.author, t.rating
FROM reviews r
JOIN(SELECT *
  FROM posts p
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM posts pt
    WHERE pt.threadid = p.threadid AND pt.positionid <= p.positionid
  ) <= 1) t
ON t.threadid = r.tid AND r.author = 'usr1';
```

And this works in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7275f5/1), though I recommend testing it on your entire dataset first.

**NOTE** The above will look a little different from your result set, because I used your idea and removed a row with positionID 1 to make sure that the next row would be used. It worked as expected.

Comment: yes it did. But the other one seemed a bit shorter,and I too ended up with something very close to that with my own trial queries. I wish I could mark both as accepted. :) Thanks very much for your help!